# Google Mapsの現在地ボタンが表示されない

Tags: android, google-maps

はじめまして。最近アプリ開発を始めてGoogle Mapsを使ったアプリ制作を試みている者です。

サンプルを参考にNew project→Google Maps Activityからプロジェクトを作成し、APIキーを取得し現在地ボタン、渋滞状況などの実装まではうまくいきました。

しかし、Android 6.0にアップデートすると実装した機能が全て動かなくなりました。

よろしければご教授お願いします。

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: API level 23 では [Run Time Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) の対応が必要になります。コメントアウトしている箇所の英文を読んでみてください。

Comment: 確認したところ，正常に動きました！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

API level 23 では [Run Time Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) の対応が必要になります。
コメントアウトしている箇所の英文を読んでみてください。

---

*この投稿は [@quesera2 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28795/google-maps%e3%81%ae%e7%8f%be%e5%9c%a8%e5%9c%b0%e3%83%9c%e3%82%bf%e3%83%b3%e3%81%8c%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment27614_28795) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*